# nestjs/node - Unable to determine event when running lambda invoke from docker or via serveless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I am using the sample example of serveless with nestjs

when I trying to invoke locally with aws after running

***sls offline --lambdaPort=4000***
and after using post request :

```
 curl -XPOST "http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/serverless-nestjs-crud-dev-main/invocations" -d '{}'
```

I have got:

```
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unable to determine event source based on event.","trace":["Error: Unable to determine event source based on event.","    at getEventSourceNameBasedOnEvent
```

in sls offline i have got

```
offline: Unhandled Lambda Error during invoke of 'serverless-nestjs-crud-dev-main'
```

also i am trying via basic docker image but the same